# Export Microsoft Access to Mysql only on Microsoft access update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft access db which I would like to link to Mysql database. When the Microsoft database updates records I want it to push the updates to Mysql database immediately. Mysql database should **NOT** be able to update the access database. Is there a way I could do it?

I am very very new to this. I tried using the ODBC export function but it is not working. I also tried using Linked tables but I am lost.

Please kindly help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access has no "triggers", so you cannot determine when a table has been updated (although 2010 does include Data Macros, which can sort of act like triggers - but that's another matter entirely).

If all your data entry is done through forms (and that's the way it should be done), then you can use the Before_Update event of the Form to do this. You mention that your tables are Linked, so essentially you just write an Update or Insert query:

```
Dim sql As String
If Not Me.NewRecord Then
  sql = "UPDATE MySQLTable1 SET Field1=" & Me.Textbox1 & " AND Field2=" & Me.Textbox2 & " WHERE      MySQLTable.IDField=" & Me.IDField
Else
  sql = "INSERT INTO MySQLTable(Field1, Field2) VALUES(" & Me.Textbox1 & "," & Me.Textbox2 & ")"
End If

Currentdb.Execute sql
```

If the Fields are Text, then you'll have to delimit them:

```
  sql = "UPDATE MySQLTable1 SET Field1='" & Me.Textbox1 & "' AND Field2='" & Me.Textbox2 & "' WHERE      MySQLTable.IDField=" & Me.IDField
```

Notice I've added single quotes ( ' ) around the actual data.

Regarding Updates: Obviously you'd have to know the ID value of the specific record in MySQL that you want to update. I'm not sure how you're storing this in order to "relate" your Access record to the MySQL record, but you'd have to do that at some level.